# KiCad: Can I insert a net name into a footprint?

Tags: kicad, footprint

I'm new to KiCad, and using version 5.1.5.

I want to make a simple single-pad footprint, with a text label that is the net name to which the corresponding schematic pin is attached. Is there a way to do this?

Similar to how `%R` and `%V` can be used to sub in component reference/value, it seems like there should be a variable for a given pin/pad's net name... but I can't find this documented anywhere.

EDIT: What also might be useful is getting the name of a component's pin. Is there a way to get this info in the footprint editor?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to me.

Answer (score 3):

A component pad will get the net name from the wire connected to it in the schematic (or a default net name, if the wire is not explicitly named.) The net name would not be part of the PCB footprint.

Comment: The net name does show up in the PCB editor labeling the pads. For nets I labeled in Eeschema, anyway (e.g., "IN," "OUT," or "GND"). I'm just hoping there's a way to access this label in the Footprint editor so that I can create, e.g., an F.SilkS label to go with the pad for off-board wiring that inherits the net name so that I don't have to manually create them every time...

Comment: This does feature does not exist at this point in time. Check [the bugtracker on gitlab](https://gitlab.com/kicad/code/kicad/issues) if it is already requested. If it is, then add your thumbs up or additional comment if you feel the report can use more detail. If there is not report yet then create one.

Answer (score 2):

This is not yet implemented but please give the following feature request a thumbs up to increase its priority:
https://gitlab.com/kicad/code/kicad/-/issues/6405